# How to query two tables in one query

Tags: sql

I have table `tags`, and I also want to count from table `questions` all rows who have in their column `tags` the `tag` name LIKE from the `tags` database.

Combine this two queries I mean:

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE 1 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `questions` WHERE `tags` 
    LIKE '%(the tag column from tags table)%'
```

Comment: I would advise reading this http://www.akadia.com/services/sqlsrv_subqueries.html or https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx They are detailed and provide good examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.name, Count(*) FROM tags t
join questions q on t.tag_id = q.tag_id
Where t.name like '%(the tag column from tags table)%'
group by t.name
```

If you are looking for `Batches of SQL Statements`

then you can do something like this by placing `;` at the end of first query

```
SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE 1 ;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `questions` WHERE `tags` 
LIKE '%(the tag column from tags table)%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have at least one field in common, use it to relate the tables:

```
SELECT t.name,q.COUNT(*) FROM questions q, tags t WHERE `tags`
LIKE t.name and q.tag=t.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear what the question is, but this is what I guess. Select all rows from tags table, and for each tag also count number of occurrences in question table:

```
select tags.*,
       (select count(*) from question
        where question.tags like '%' || tags.tag || '%')
from tags
```

`||` is ANSI SQL for concat. Some dbms products have their own ways, e.g. `concat(str1, str2)`.